# Apache mod_rewrite redirecting page assets

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web

I just started using mod_rewrite for a web project, and I had finally got it to redirect the way I wanted but I have ran into a big problem. If I redirect the request /trades/id to trades.php?id=id, the browser looks for all of the assets of trades.php inside of  the  non-existent trades/ directory instead.

Here is my .htaccess

```
# Enable Rewriting  
RewriteEngine on  

# Rewrite user URLs  
#   Input:  trades/ID/
#   Output: trades.php?id=ID
RewriteRule ^trades/(\w+)/?$ index.php?req=trades&id=$1
```

The problem that arises is that when I load the page localhost/trades/ID, The browser is attempting to load assets like so,

```
http://localhost/trades/js/cardy.js
```

which ofcourse does not exist on the server. I'm still really new to mod_rewrite, so I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Easiest way: Refer all of your external resources with a leading slash, so that they reference to the domain root.

Comment: Didn't work. Inside of my TPL file (using Smarty) I referenced assets with ./ at the beginning, same effect.

Comment: Who said something about a dot?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained a bit better, I tried without the dot at first with no luck, nothing loaded at all (even on index.php), tried with a dot and assets on index loaded but I had the same effect of nothing loading with the mod_rewrite. I found out what i was doing wrong though, and your advice worked like a charm! I have been working in a sub directory, not my document root, so as soon as I added /sub/, everything worked like it should. Thanks again!